# AIML Bot on Android

Tags: android, aiml

I am developing a Virtual Assistant bot for Android (similar to Pandorabots Callmom) for my academic project.

Till now I could make my bot to reply like a chatbot using AIML files using Program AB.

I used this tutorial for reference: https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-baking-a-simple-chatbot-in-30-minutes-aiml-ff43c3269025#.drkiywk14

But when I ask it to search android it replies 
`I’ll try a web search <oob><search>android</search></oob>.`

It just shows the oob tag associated with the action instead of performing it.

Can anyone please help me solve my problem?

[Here is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6QRB.png)

I am using the AIML files provided [in this archive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxILBrhfU04VSlIxOEZkVXdmVTg).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote my own code which scans the file line-by-line and does my work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not closed the `<srai>` tag before opening the `<oob>` tag. Please post your code.

Comment: You mean the AIML file?

Comment: I have added the link to the archive that contains the AIML files.